# How to reduce a git branch history before merging a PR

Tags: git, github, branch

I'm wondering how to clean up history in a branch before merging my work to the Master using git on GitHub.

Is enough to do? :

```
git rebase -i master
```

then

adding squash in front of every commit to be hidden or there's a better way to do that?

Comment: I believe squashing your history before merge is enough. Github even offers to do that for you directly on the PR review page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably the safest.

If you're more comfortable with git, and have a lot of commits so that `git rebase -i` gives you a very long list, you could also do `git reset $(git merge-base origin/master HEAD)`, and then re-commit your changes as one single commit.

Comment: Thanks @Mort for this ! Actually, in GitHub you can directly do this via the PR interface but I'll give it a try as it seems more generic.

Comment: @Mort @awzx that's better to use the option `--soft` to keep all the changes in the index/staging area. It's more convenient and that way you could do it even with a dirty workspace.

Comment: Thanks, actually, the easiest way on GitHub was to squash directly from the PR view, but I like also this approach https://gist.github.com/patik/b8a9dc5cd356f9f6f980